# How to make the left and right border of a card in ionic transparent

Tags: html, css

The below is my HTML. I have a total of 3 cards in three columns and want only the left and right side to be transparent. I have tried setting border to white/transparent but no success.[image: what I am getting currently]
. What I want[image: what I want]

```css
.user-panel .card {
  margin-top: 1px;
}

.user-panel {
  min-height: 170px;
}

.user-panel,
.user-panel .card {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.user-panel,
.user-panel .card .item {
  height: inherit;
  text-align: center;
}

.user-panel .user-profile-details .item {
  background-color: #edfaff;
}
```

```html
<div class="row no-padding user-panel">
  <div class="col col-33 no-padding">
    <div class="card  no-padding">
      <div class="item item-text-wrap">
        <span>
          <div>
            <div class="row"><i class="user-profile-icon"></i> </div>
              <div>{{data}}</div>
              <div>(015106)</div>
              </div>
         </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-33 no-padding">
    <div class="card  no-padding">
      <div class="item item-text-wrap">
        <span>
          <div>
            <div>MY ACCESSES</div>
           </div>
         </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col col-33 no-padding">
    <div class="card  no-padding">
      <div class="item item-text-wrap">
        <span>
          <div>
            <div>MY ACCESSES</div>
          </div>
         </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Share your css?

Comment: @cosmoonot I have added my CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why do u use card. Just give some custom class name and define css for that. Something Like below would work without flaws.

```
<div class="col col-33 no-padding">
    <div class="card-access  no-padding">
        <div class="item item-text-wrap">
            <span>
                           <div>
                               <div>MY ACCESSES</div>
                           </div>
                       </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    .user-panel .card {
       border: 1px solid #ccc;
//remove  this
    }


//add this
    .bordered-col {
        border-right : 1px solid #ccc;
    }

<div class="row no-padding user-panel">
    <div class="bordered-col col col-33 no-padding">
        <div class="card  no-padding">
            <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                <span>
                               <div>
                                   <div class="row"><i class="user-profile-icon"></i> </div>
                                   <div>{{data}}</div>
                                   <div>(015106)</div>
                               </div>
                           </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-33 no-padding">
        <div class="card  no-padding">
            <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                <span>
                               <div>
                                   <div>MY ACCESSES</div>
                               </div>
                           </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col col-33 no-padding">
        <div class="card  no-padding">
            <div class="item item-text-wrap">
                <span>
                               <div>
                                   <div>MY ACCESSES</div>
                               </div>
                           </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: the border is because of card not column.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a `class` in each **MY ACCESS** e.g. `<div class="access1">MY ACCESS</div>` and `<div class="access2">MY ACCESS</div>` then add this css styles:

```
.no-padding > span > .access1{
   border-right: 0;
}

.no-padding > span > .access2{
   border-left: 0;
}
```

Please include your css styles too, so we can figure your problem. Leave a comment if it doesn't work.